# How to foreach categories from 3rd index from my database / Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am issuing a problem with the following:

I foreach-ed my categories from index 1 to 3 in my blade file.

Code

```
@foreach($categories->take(3) as $category)
<ul>
<li>{{$category->name}}</li>
</ul>
@endforeach
```

But now I want to foreach second half of my categories from my database on the other ul list.

How to do that..?

Thanks:)

Comment: From 3rd index till which index?

Comment: To the last index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`splice`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-splice) method
to popout the first 3 elements and then use another foreach to create another `ul` list from the other categories like below:

```
<?php

@foreach($categories->splice(0, 3) as $category)
<ul>
  <li><a>{{ $category->name }}</a>
</ul>
@endforeach

@foreach($categories as $category)
<ul>
  <li><a>{{ $category->name }}</a>
</ul>
@endforeach
```